# How to convert pdf bytes files to normal files?

Tags: python, img2pdf

I have this function written in pyhon.
It takes a list of .pdf file objects and merges them into one .pdf file.

My problem is, that some of the files in the list are regular files and the merge fine, but some are byte files and they won't merge.

This is the code creating the bytes files from image objects and adding them to the list.

```
with open('file.pdf','wb') as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(img))
    pdf_filer.append(f)
    img.close()
```

I can't see a way to convert the bytes files into ordinary files. How is that done?

```
def merge_pdfs(paths, output):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for path in paths:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(path)
        for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            # Add each page to the writer object
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    # Write out the merged PDF
    with open(output, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)
```

Comment: In this line:  with open(file.pdf,'wb') as f  , are you sure ,that you haven't missed the quotations for the string?

Comment: You are right. In the script the filename is auto generated. I took that part out before I posted.

Comment: What I still don't understand is what kind of an error you get

Comment: What's a "normal file"?

Comment: Printing to type of the "normal" files get <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'> the rest gives <class '_io.BufferedWriter'>

Comment: This is the error I get:  File "C:\Users\kbu\Downloads\python\flaksapp\app.py", line 17, in merge_pdf spdf_reader = PdfFileReader(path)

io.UnsupportedOperation: read

Comment: In your first snippet, you add file objects to some sort of collection. In your second snippet, you iterate over some collection and call the items "path". This makes me suspicious. File objects are not paths. I suspect, but do now know for certain, that your problem is that you are trying to read from a file object opened in write (the 'w' in 'wb') mode.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: You are creating your file objects in a `with` statement, which makes sure they are closed at the end of the statement. So not only were they write-only when they were open, they are not even open anymore!